# Mod_proxy , apache and node.js in one url

Tags: node.js, apache, mod-proxy

So i got a node.js api server and a apache webserver both on the same server. The problem is the node.js server has to be connected like this (111.111.11:3000) that would be the ip of the server itself and the port of the node attached to it, while the apache server is on the domain itself (mydomain.com).

Now my question is what does mod_proxy actually do? Does it allow me to acess my node routings by just using the apache domain.

For example is i would be needing to acess the routing /api/getbla i would be typing this in the search bar 111.111.11:3000/api/getbla.

Will mod_proxy allow me to do it like this instead mydomain.ocm/api/getbla?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I tried myself and it did work. The reversed proxy allowed my node server to act like its a part of apache. Example i could acess the api by just typing the domain name.